# split arcgis string field with mutiple delimiters into new text file in Python

Tags: python, string, text-files, arcgis

I've got a table in ArcGIS 10.2 with a string field. I need to split this field out into a text file with each P_XXXX on a separate line. What is the best method to split the table on multiple delimiters (we have ',' and '&') and write out into a new text file?

Many Thanks
[Example ArcGIS table with P_XXXX string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYehx.jpg)

Comment: Replace one delimiter with the other, then do the split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an example I put some of the text in list, and then used regex for finding relevant tokens.

```
import re

file_to_write = open('tokens.txt','wb')
attribute = ['P_10490','P_9912,P_9916','P_9914,P_9915,P_9918']

for item in attribute:
    tokens = re.findall('(P_[0-9]+)', item)
    for t in tokens:
        file_to_write.write(t + '\n')

file_to_write.close()
```